# wmic useraccount list full and nothing happen

Tags: command-line-interface, wmic

the result is blank. is there any solution to make it show

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5lGz.png

Answer (score 2):

When a system is joined to a domain, the default functionality of "wmic useraccount" is to enum all users in the domain.  For even medium sized domains, it's not good at doing this.  This query can be filtered / limited to a single system with a "where" clause:

## CMD:

```
wmic.exe useraccount where "localaccount=true" get name,sid,disabled
```

## OUTPUT:

```
Disabled  Name                SID
TRUE      Administrator       S-1-5-21-27797481-235746463-772742770-500
FALSE     Me-Admin            S-1-5-21-27797481-235746463-772742770-1001
FALSE     Me-NonAdmin         S-1-5-21-27797481-235746463-772742770-1002
TRUE      DefaultAccount      S-1-5-21-27797481-235746463-772742770-503
TRUE      Guest               S-1-5-21-27797481-235746463-772742770-501
FALSE     ToolBox             S-1-5-21-27797481-235746463-772742770-1007
TRUE      WDAGUtilityAccount  S-1-5-21-27797481-235746463-772742770-504
```